# Looking for examples in C++ for the /Message resource

Tags: twilio, sms, message

I currently have an application that uses some of the Twilio Rest calls to receive a response and log the event. I'm looking to see what I can do to migrate to the Messages Resource URI and some example in C++ would be helpful although I suspect I can use the PHP example and rewrite them.
It seems Twilio doesn't formally support the C++. I'm using C++ because the rest of the system uses C and C++.
Thanks

Searching the Twilio API docs

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not support C++, but you should just be calling the endpoint directly with a URL which you can do in multiple languages.